# Memory Issue in IIS WCF Service when creating reports using ActiveReports

Tags: wcf, iis, activereports

We have a requirement to generate reports automatically on schedule basis through WCFService hosted in IIS. The report is created using ActiveReports. Previously, we were generating report through a windows application in our machine. The issue that we are currently encountering is out of memory exception. When we try to run 2MB reports, it works fine but when we try to run 4MB reports, it is not processing. It throws out of memory exception. Our server has 4GB RAM, 8GB virtual memory and windows7 OS. Please advice us on how to solve this issue.

Comment: You need to find out whether ActiveReports supports being used in a server application. It may be written for desktop applications only.

Comment: BTW: ActiveReports is most commonly used in ASP.NET server applications and is certainly written with server applications in mind. Although, it is only a component that does what the developer tells it, so scalability must be considered by the developer.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if you have the available memory and the report is *really* 2-4MB then the report will run. I suspect the report is much more than the 2-4MB in memory or the machine doesn't have much memory available. A good way to see what is going on is run a memory profiler like [Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) or [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). Keep in mind that in addition to the data you're going to load for the report, any images or content in the pages of the report will also be in memory. And if you export it to another format like PDF, there will be some additional overhead to hold that PDF in memory.

Also, we now offer [ActiveReports Server](http://www.activereportsserver.com/) too which has built in scheduling and web services for requesting reports in a specific format (implemented via WCF obviously). It will deal with scalability by automatically queuing, caching, and load balancing report executions as needed. You can also upload your ActiveReports .rpx reports from the Developer Edition and get up and running right away. Just make sure all the code for your report is self-contained in the .rpx (script).

```
Scott Willeke
GrapeCity
```